# GetStream.io get reaction's extra returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, getstream-io

I just add a like with this piece of code:

```
    val client = CloudClient.builder(API_KEY, token, user).build()
    val like = Reaction.Builder().kind("like").activityID(activityID).userID(user).extraField("extraUserID", userID).build()
    return client.reactions().add(user, like).get()
```

When I want to get it via:

```
fun createJsonWithReaction(r: Reaction): String {
    val rid = r.id
    val activityID = r.activityID
    val kind = r.kind
    val userID = r.userID
    val extraUserID = r.extra["extraUserID"]
    val text = r.extra["text"]
    return "{\"id\":\"$rid\", \"activityID\":\"$activityID\", \"kind\":\"$kind\", \"userID\":\"$userID\", \"extraUserID\":\"$extraUserID\", \"text\":\"$text\"}"
}
```

r.extra["extraUserID"] will be null
and
r.extra["text"] will be null

What is the probleme here?

**SOLUTION**

lol it looks like

**extra**

will be

**activityData**

**naming conventions error o the API?
Why I need to set with extraField and get via activityData? WTF?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

lol it looks like

```
extra
```

will be

```
activityData
```

naming conventions probleme in the library itself